# LDSET ARM instruction as inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to use the Atomic LDSET ARM Instruction (http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_asm/armclang_asm_chi1476202820379.htm) as an inline assembly code in C, but somehow I am not able to figure out the right operands. 
I wrote this

```
int value = 1024; //operate on this value
int setBit = 7; //set the 7th bit
int initValue = 0; //return the original value in this
asm("ldset %w0, %w2, %x1" : "+r"(value), "=r"(initValue) : "r"(setBit));
```

and got this error :

```
test-lib.cpp:26:9: error: invalid operand for instruction
  asm("ldset %w0, %w2, %x1" : "+r"(value), "=r"(initValue) : "r"(setBit));
      ^
<inline asm>:1:17: note: instantiated into assembly here
      ldset w9, w10, x10
                     ^
```

Need some help on this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [page you linked](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_asm/armclang_asm_chi1476202820379.htm), the third operand must be a memory reference, and one which uses just a single register without an offset. The [`Q` constraint is for specifically this purpose](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html), so try:

```
asm("ldset %w0, %w2, %1" : "+r"(value), "=Q"(initValue) : "r"(setBit));
```

This should generate something like `ldset w0, w1, [x2]`.